# Child view not loading in named view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Following is my parent/root HTML and JS code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router"])
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("parent", {
                templateUrl: 'Parent.html',
                controller: 'ParentController'
            })
            .state('parent.child', {
                views: {
                    'childView@parent': {
                        templateUrl: 'Child.html',
                        controller: 'ChildController'
                    }
                }
            })
    })
    .controller("ParentController", function ($scope, $state) {
        $scope.currentTime = new Date();
        $scope.count = 1;
        $scope.LoadChildView = function () {
            $state.go("parent.child");
        }
        $scope.Increment = function () {
            $scope.count += 1;
        }
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="../../../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Parent.js"></script>
    <script src="Child.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ParentController">
    Current time: {{currentTime}}
    <input type="button" ng-click="Increment()" value="Increment" />
    Count: {{count}}
    <div>
        <input type="button" ng-click="LoadChildView()" value="Load" />
    </div>
    <div ui-view="childView"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on "Load" button, the contents/HTML of child.html is not loaded in ui-view="childView" of parent.

Comment: What is the url for your child and parent view?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ng-controller` when using `ui.router`

`index.html` should have nothing but your root view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then Parent.html

```
Current time: {{currentTime}}
<input type="button" ng-click="Increment()" value="Increment" />
Count: {{count}}
<div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="LoadChildView()" value="Load" />
</div>
<div ui-view="childView"></div>
```

The original code is lacking the parent `ui-view` layer so the child view has no place to replace itself.

Comment: Thanks. Probably I am missing something in my basic understanding, but is it mandatory to have index.html with unnamed ui-view? The html containing my parent controller is my start page and I expected the child view to render inside ui-view="childView".

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Yes you can do that, treating `parent` as a "root" and doesn't need to be mentioned in routing. Then you can set `child` as a first level state. It is similar to the [tutorial](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld)